# EF Code First: Methods that can translate to SQL

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first, expression-trees

I'm looking for a way to create a function that can be used in my Linq queries that will translate to SQL. Back when we were using Linq-to-SQL, I posed a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790744/creating-methods-that-do-translate-to-sql). The answer was to map to a UDF in the db. We're using the code first model because of the cleanliness of the model definition, but unfortunately there is no way to [define functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456812.aspx), map to functions, and map to stored procs as far as I can tell (I guess the idea being that code first should generate the db, and I shouldn't be adding things to it). Doesn't seem very scale-able to me, since it allows no easy method for dealing with inefficiencies that may evolve over time, but that's neither here nor there...

Anyway, I know I can define predicate expressions that will translate to SQL that I can use in my queries like so:

```
public static Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> FilterMe(int comparisonNumber)
{
    return x => x.SomeProperty == comparisonNumber;
}

var query = MyEntities.Where(FilterMe(1));
```

Is this only possible for Expressions that return `bool`? I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
var query = from m in MyEntities
            let endDate = GetEndDate(m.Start, m.Duration)
            where endDate <= DateTime.Now
            select m;
```

Is there some way to build `GetEndDate` in an expression function? The code within `GetEndDate` translates to SQL just fine when I write it long-hand in the query, but it's pretty long and confusing to read.

Edit - Oh and before someone answers with "Use SQLFunctions for DateAdd", my example is just that..an example. There are countless other ways I'd like to use this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try it?  i.e., return an `Expression<Func<MyEntity, DateTime>>` and make the query `where GetEndDate(m) <= DateTime.Now`.

Comment: Yes, and that won't work. You'll get something along the lines of "Can't compare `Expression<Func<MyEntity, DateTime>>` and `DateTime`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try LinqKit: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx
with .AsExpandable() and .Compile(), it allows the use of Expressions in your Linq queries.